# Returning an API response as JSON from C# to angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, response

I am returning data from API but when I try to parse it as a JSON in Angular ts it says "Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'", what I want to do is to get the json response from API as [{name:"name1"},{name:"name2"}] rather than [{"name":"name1"},{"name":"name2"}] which doesnt write the name on csv file

```cs
        [HttpGet("getEmployees")]
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<EmployeesView>))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployeesByCreateDate(DateTime period)
        {
        
            try
            {
                // read model returns users by a logic as enumerable  
                return Ok(await _readModel.GetEmployees(period));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // throw exception
            }
```

**myService.ts**

```js
getAllPosts() {
      return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.URL).subscribe((data: any) => {return data;});
    }
      
download(data, filename='data') { 
    let csvData=this.ConvertToCSV(data, ['name1','name2']); 
    let blob = new Blob(['\ufeff' + csvData],{type:'text/csv;charset=utf8;'}); 
    let dwldLink = document.createElement("a");
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    dwldLink.setAttribute("href", url);
    dwldLink.setAttribute("download", filename + ".csv");
    dwldLink.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(dwldLink); 
    dwldLink.click();
}

  ConvertToCSV(objArray, headerList) {
    let array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    let str = '';
    let row = 'S.No,';
    for (let index in headerList) {
      row += headerList[index] + ',';
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
    str += row + '\r\n';
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let line = i + 1 + '';
      for (let index in headerList) {
        let head = headerList[index];
        line += ',' + array[i][head];
      }
      str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
  }
```

**myComponent.ts**

```js
JsonData = JSON.parse( this.URL.getAllPosts());
        
download2(){ this.URL.download(this.JsonData, 'jsontocsv'); } //here is the problem
```

I want to return my data as :

```json
        [
         {
          name:"name1",
          surname:"surname1"
         },
         {
          name:"name2",
          surname:"surname2"
         }
        ]
```

But instead I get it like this (I need it in format as above becuase I am downloading the data I get as CSV)

```json
        [
         {
          "name":"name1",
          "surname":"surname1"
         },
         {
          "name":"name2",
          "surname":"surname2"
         }
        ]
```

Comment: thank you The code works but when I type a JSON manually i can see those in dowloaded csv file, the problem is when get json from API and save it to a variable and pass it to the function that creates csv it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `subscribe()` is a `Subscription`, which is used to unsubscribe later. `subscribe()` does not return your data, it saves your callback function for executing later, once it receives a response. Unsubscribing from a simple http request is not necessary since it will complete after the first response.

You can either do whatever you want to do inside your callback function, or you can use `async`, `await`, and `firstValueFrom()` to get more synchronous looking code.

Also, you don't need to parse it, this is done automatically through the `HttpClient` service.

```js
async getAllPosts(): Promise<IEmployee[]> {
    return await firstValueFrom(this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.URL));
}
```

```js
JsonData = await this.URL.getAllPosts();
```

**OR**

```js
getAllPosts(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.URL);
}
```

```js
this.URL.getAllPosts().subscribe((data) => JsonData = data);
```

---

Following your edits, this solution should work for you:

**In your service**

```js
async getAllPosts(): Promise<IEmployee[]> {
    return await firstValueFrom(this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.URL));
}
```

**In your component**

```js
async download2() { 
  this.URL.download(await this.URL.getAllPosts(), 'jsontocsv'); 
}
```

---

I see another issue with your download function, you have:

```js
let csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(data, ['name1','name2'])
```

When it should be:

```js
let csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(data, ['name', 'surname']);
```

---

To implement using callbacks instead of promises:

**In your service**

```js
getAllPosts(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.URL);
}
```

**In your component**

```js
download2() { 
  this.URL.getAllPosts().subscribe((data) => this.URL.download(data, 'jsontocsv')); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but still my problem is when I get data from API it wont create a csv, and when I do it manually typing a json array it somehow works

Comment: Could you please log the response from your API call and show it? In your question you've shown two identical outputs so I don't see the issue. Also, if the error comes from creating a csv file, you should show that code.

Comment: You are right I will try to ask another way, sorry for that

Comment: basically response from the api is like this : [
 {
  "name":"name1",
  "surname":"surname1"
 },
 {
  "name":"name2",
  "surname":"surname2"
 }
] but when i type  [
 {
  name:"name1",
  surname:"surname1"
 },
 {
  name:"name2",
  surname:"surname2"
 }
] which is without quotes on left side it creates my csv file

Comment: download2(){
    this.URL.download(this.JsonData, 'jsontocsv');
  } and in my service it is download(data, filename='data') {
  let csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(data, ['name1','name2']);
  let blob = new Blob(['\ufeff' + csvData], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
  let dwldLink = document.createElement("a");
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  dwldLink.setAttribute("href", url);
  dwldLink.setAttribute("download", filename + ".csv");
  dwldLink.style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.body.appendChild(dwldLink);
  dwldLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(dwldLink);
}

Comment: The quotes make no difference. My guess is you're attempting to create the csv file before your http request has completed. Please **edit your question** and add all relevant code.

Comment: I did edit it, thank you for the suggestions hopefully this is more clear now, the quotes difference is im guessing that becuase when I type manually a json array without quotes it is working but when i type it with quotes it doesnt work

Comment: I've made a second edit as I saw an error in your download function.

Comment: Quotations make no difference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbzt3l?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yeah it works in stackblitz thats strange but still not working in my project, Im trying to do implement your edit but I cant import  firstValueFrom from rxjs and vs code doesnt recognize it, my angular version is 7.3.10, how can i try that method, I also tried it by updating to angular 13 but again no luck ?

Comment: For older versions you can try `await this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.URL).toPromise()`

Comment: I've edited my answer again to show how to implement using callbacks instead of promises.